# Irreducibility of a polynomial over certain finite fields

Tags: galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $f$ be irreducible over $\mathbb F_{p^k}$. I want to show that $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb F_{p^{km}}$ if, and only if, $\gcd(\deg f,m)=1.$

I've been racking my brain on this for some time now, but can't get anything started. Any *pushes* in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d$ be the degree of $f$ and $q=p^k$.
Let $\alpha$ be a zero of $f$ is the algebraic closure of $\Bbb F_q$.
Then $\Bbb F_q(\alpha)=\Bbb F_{q^{d}}$. Now $f$ is irreducible over
$\Bbb F_{q^m}$ iff $\Bbb F_{q^m}(\alpha)=\Bbb F_{q^{md}}$.
But $\Bbb F_{q^m}(\alpha)$ is the compositum of the 
extensions $\Bbb F_{q^d}$ and $\Bbb F_{q^m}$ of $\Bbb F_q$. As
$\Bbb F_q$ has precisely one extension of a given degree, then
the compositum of $\Bbb F_{q^d}$ and $\Bbb F_{q^m}$ is $\Bbb F_{q^{
\text{lcm}(d,m)}}$. So for $f$ to be irreducible over $\Bbb F_{q^m}$
it's necessary and sufficient that $\text{lcm}(d,m)=dm$, equivalently
$\gcd(d,m)=1$.